# Error creating Flutter Sqflite_ffi database for windows

Tags: windows, flutter, flutter-dependencies, sqflite

I've tried many ways and different tutorials.
My database is working fine on android and the app is working. but when it comes to Windows, it doesn't work. I'm trying to open an existing database, it's in assets directory, I need to config it for windows, here is my code:

```
class DatabaseHelper {

  static final columnId = '_id';
  static final columnNome = 'nome';
  static final columnIdade = 'idade';

  // torna esta classe singleton
  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  // // tem somente uma referência ao banco de dados
  // static Database? _database;

  Future<Database?> get database async {
    sqfliteFfiInit();

    var databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;
    var databasesPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    var path = join(databasesPath.path, "barcode.db");
    print(databasesPath);

    // Verifica se a database existe
    var exists = await databaseExists(path);

    if (!exists) {
      // Should happen only the first time you launch your application
      print("Creating new copy from asset");

      // Make sure the parent directory exists
      try {
        await Directory(dirname(path)).create(recursive: true);
      } catch (_) {}

      // Copy from asset
      ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join("assets", "barcode-barcode.db"));
      List<int> bytes =
      data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);

      // Write and flush the bytes written
      await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);

    } else {
      print("Opening existing database");
    }

// open the database
    var db = await openDatabase(path);
    return db;
  }
```